# Using a value converter to bind to Visibility in universal app

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, resourcedictionary, ivalueconverter

Next, we need to create a converter to go between bool values and Visibility.  Here's that:

```
   namespace DictionaryApp.Model
{
    public class VisiableConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object Convert(
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool visibility = (bool)value;
            return visibility ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(
            object value,
            Type targetType,
            object parameter,
            CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Visibility visibility = (Visibility)value;
            return (visibility == Visibility.Visible);
        }
    }
}
```

Next, add the converter in the UserControl's resources.  In my simple project, I had to create this section - but hopefully you're already using this in your real apps!

You may also need to add an xmlns attribute in page.xaml for your project's namespace.

```
x:Class="DictionaryApp.PageDictionary"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:DictionaryApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ms="using:DictionaryApp.Model"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ms:VisiableConverter x:Key="VisiableConverter"></ms:VisiableConverter>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

***The name “XYZ” does not exist in the namespace “axy***

Comment: try this: `<local:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter" />`, the VisibilityConverter class is defined without specifying a namespace, so it should be inside the global namespace, which is `DictionaryApp`, that is why I use the `local:` prefix.

Comment: you mean my code works, but then you tried adding the `DictionaryApp.Model` namespace, and you got a new error?

Comment: Here "The name “XYZ” does not exist in the namespace “axy"

Comment: What are "XYZ" and "axy" in your case?